# express-validation sequential processing

Tags: express, promise, express-validator, promise.all

I am following this guide [running-imperatively](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/running-imperatively) and trying to implement the sequential processing sample.

```
const validate = validations => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    for (let validation of validations) {
      const result = await validation.run(req);
      if (result.errors.length) break;
    }

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
      return next();
    }

    res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  };
};
```

The only significant eslint error I can't get around is [no-await-in-loop](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-await-in-loop)
Here is the current state of my code

One of the differences from the above sample is I'm not sending `res` in this middleware; instead, it's passed on to `next`

```
const validate = (validations) => async (req, res, next) => {
  const validationPromises = [];

  // lodash function :)
  _.forEach(validations, (validation) => {
    const validationPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      validation.run(req).then((result) => {
        if (result.errors.length) {
          reject('Error');
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
    validationPromises.push(validationPromise);
  });

  Promise.all(validationPromises).then(next).catch(next);
};
```

The issue that I see is even though I'm `reject`ing if the validation run has an error, all the validations are still executed.

I have ensured the `reject` is correctly called, but all the Promiss are still executed. I'd expect if any Promise within `Promise.all` was rejected, it would stop the execution of the rest of the Promises.

Here is how the validate middleware is called,

```
router.post(
  '/submit',
  validate([
    body('challenge')
      .notEmpty({ ignore_whitespace: true })
      .withMessage('Invalid request. Please try login again'),
    body('email').isEmail().withMessage('Please provide a valid email'),
    body('comment')
      .notEmpty({ ignore_whitespace: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a valid comment'),
    body('tosChecked')
      .isBoolean()
      .withMessage('Please select Terms of service'),
  ]),
  (req, res, next) => {
   ...
  }
);
```

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: "*The only significant eslint error I can't get around is no-await-in-loop*" - it's not an error, it's a warning, and since you **want** sequential processing, you should simply **ignore** or even better disable that annoying rule. The authors [even recommend that](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-await-in-loop#when-not-to-use-it).

Comment: Btw, [avoid the Promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) with `validationPromise`. "*I'd expect if any Promise within Promise.all was rejected, it would stop the execution of the rest of the Promises.*" - no. The whole point of starting the execution of all `validation.run()` calls in a loop, collecting the promises in an array, and then using `Promise.all` to wait until all are done, is to make them run concurrently - not what you want! And when an exception happens, you cannot stop the calls that were already made.

Comment: @Bergi, well errors and warning from eslint are contextual to the user based on the configuration. Thanks for the link btw!